# GraphQL mutation with variables from within a lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, apollo-client

I used to be able to call a GraphQL endpoint from within an AWS lambda function using `Apollo-fetch` but that library is no longer maintained.

Are there any alternatives that are lightweight and suitable for the fast execution requirements of lambda?

Comment: If you just need to fire off a mutation and don't need advanced client features like caching, any HTTP client will do but you could also just use the [core library](https://nodejs.dev/making-http-requests-with-nodejs#perform-a-post-request).

Comment: Thank you Daniel, the problem is I'm unable to send a json object variable correctly using a normal http fetch library.

Comment: You're welcome to edit your question with how you're attempting to do this. If there's an issue, it's usually either with the headers being sent or the way you're formatting the body (assuming the query itself is valid).